# if variable equals 1 (java)

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

At the end of my code, I want to check if the user wants to try everything again. So I ask
them to input 1. I want to check if the input is 1, and if so, I run the program again.

The problem is, it ignores the condition and always decides to run the program again.

```
int input = readInt("1 = yes, 0 = no: ");
if (input == 1); {
    run();
}
```

Even if a number different than 1 is input, it still performs `run();` .
I only want it to do that if the input number is 1.

I am obviously making a rookie mistake but I cannot seem to figure out what it is. Any pointers?

Comment: Check the `;` after your condition. What do you think that does?

Comment: It appears I have misunderstood how if conditions work. Thank you.

Comment: @user2946352 i don't think so ;) there was just a pitfall you didn't know yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because the function run is reachable anyhow, notice the ";"

Your code

```
int input = readInt("1 = yes, 0 = no: ");
if (input == 1); { // checks if input is 1, executes run anyhow
    run();
}
```

do this instead

```
int input = readInt("1 = yes, 0 = no: ");
if (input == 1) { // checks if input is 1, then executes run
    run();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your if statement will be block with the appearance of `;` at the end of `if (input == 1);`
Actually your `run`  method is like:

```
{
run();
}
```

Which will be always execute.